# Disabling impact damage by Kinematic actor on non-dynamic destructibles (using NVidia APEX)

Tags: physx

I have a destructible non-dynamic object at Apex scene and am hitting the object with a *kinematic* actor. I do not want it to be fractured by these impacts. Is it possible?

PS: the impact damage is off when the destructible is dynamic. I have tried below settings:

```
physx::apex::NxDestructibleParameters destructibleParameters = 
                                          destructibleActor->getDestructibleParameters();
destructibleParameters.forceToDamage = 0;
destructibleParameters.damageCap = 0;
destructibleParameters.impactVelocityThreshold = PX_MAX_F32;
destructibleParameters.impactDamageDefaultDepth = -10;
destructibleActor->setDestructibleParameters(destructibleParameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting *damageThreshold* handled it:

```
...
NxParameterized::Interface* descParams = destructibleAsset->getDefaultActorDesc();
NxParameterized::setParamF32(*descParams, "defaultBehaviorGroup.damageThreshold", -1.0f);
NxApexActor* tempActor = destructibleAsset->createApexActor(*descParams, scene.getApexScene();
```